# unable to show session message in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I set session message in my class file like `$_SESSION['op_status'] = 'MY MESSAGE HERE';` then redirect the page `header("location:news.php");` Page redirects to `news.php` but session message is not displaying.

config.php:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   // DATABASE CONFIURATION GOES HERE
?>
```

news.php:

```
<?php
  require_once 'config.php';
  require_once 'classes/class.news.php';
  $objNews = new News();

  if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'add')
   $objNews->add();

?>

<span class='text-warning'><?php echo $_session['op_status']; ?></span>
```

class.news.php:

```
public function add() {
  if(){
     // SOME CODE GOES HERE
  } else {
     $_SESSION['op_status'] == 'Already Exist';
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you started your session before you used it in both files? (`session_start();`)

Comment: Yes, I added session_start() in config file and included the config file in news file. require_once('config.php');

Comment: Then please show us both scripts here

Comment: See this page http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and compare the session variable with what you presently have. `echo $_session['op_status'];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use exit() just after header().

```
 $_SESSION['msg']="Hello";
 header("Location: account.php");
 exit();
```

then in account.php use

```
 echo $_SESSION['msg'];
```

Make sure `session_start();` is on every page where you want to show/create session messages.

Instead of using this way, I prefer to use below function. (to distinguish if it was error message or success as in Bootstrap HTML markup)

```
 function _redirect($url=NULL, $message=NULL, $message_type=NULL){
      $_SESSION['sess_flash_message']= array();
      if($message){
          switch($message_type){ 
            case 'success': $_SESSION['sess_flash_message'][] = '<div class="alert alert-success"><button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>'.$message.'</div>';break;
            case 'error': $_SESSION['sess_flash_message'][] = '<div class="alert alert-error"><button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>'.$message.'</div>';break;
            case 'notice': $_SESSION['sess_flash_message'][] = '<div class="alert alert-info"><button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>'.$message.'</div>';break;
            case 'warning': $_SESSION['sess_flash_message'][] = '<div class="alert alert-block"><button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>'.$message.'</div>';break;
            default: $_SESSION['sess_flash_message'][] = $message;
          }
      }
    if($url) {
        header("Location: ".$url);
    } else {
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
     exit();
     ob_flush();    
}
```

and call `_redirect('login.php','You need to login first!','warning');`

Answer (score 3):

You have to change:

```
$_session['op_status']
```

to:

```
$_SESSION['op_status']
```

Because `$_SESSION` is a superglobal and must be uppercase.

Also as a reference see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Also you do a comparison here:

```
$_SESSION['op_status'] == 'Already Exist';
```

And i think you want to assign it so change it to this:

```
$_SESSION['op_status'] = 'Already Exist';
```

Also I hope you have a condition in your `if` statement, otherwise it doesn't work.

**Nota:** Make sure that `session_start();` resides inside all pages using sessions.

---

**Side Note:**

You can add error reporting in testing environment with:

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

// rest of your code below
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you havent started or continued the session

```
<?php
session_start();

// your code
?>
```

Another option is to pass your message through the URL.This is how you header them off:

```
$myMessage = "<YOUR MESSAGE HERE>";
header("Location: http://www.somesite.com/news.php?mymessage=" . $myMessage);
```

Then on news.php:

```
$theMessage = $_GET['mymessage'];
```

Comment: I cant pass any variables on URL. I would like to have pretty URL

Comment: I wouldn't go with the `$_GET` suggestion from a security standpoint as it opens up your site for parameter manipulation. I.e. it allows everyone that fiddles around with the URL to let your site display a message.